# VIEW intent not work for mi file explorer

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, xiaomi

I'm trying to open `.txt` file from the [mi file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer). But every time it opens [WPS office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng) instead of the app selector.

Everything works for other apps or without WPS, for example, I can select my app by opening file in gmail.

Is there something special for mi file explorer to handle `android.intent.action.VIEW`?

Intent filter in target app:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="file" />
   <data android:scheme="content" />
   <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

The intent log from file explorer:

```
I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/test_folder/test_file.txt typ=text/plain flg=0x1 cmp=cn.wps.moffice_eng/cn.wps.moffice.documentmanager.PreStartActivity3 (has extras)} from uid 10155
```

Comment: Try with two intent-filter's. For both schemes one. Or remove the schemes completely.

Comment: @blackapps Same result, I have tried two intent-filter's with different schemes and one intent-filter with * scheme.

Comment: Then the only thing left you can do is send me your xiaomi ;-).

Comment: @blackapps I have just realized, that it is a file explorer behavior. I'll update the question

Comment: `and one intent-filter with * scheme. ` ?? What do you mean? Did you try without schemes? Remove both lines.

Comment: Same, but manifest shows "Missing URL"